# Expected value of square root transformation of a normal random variable

Tags: probability

Suppose you have a random variable $X(t) \sim N(X_{0}, \sigma^2t)$ and there is a trasformation $G(x) = \sqrt x, x \geq 0$ and $G(x) = 0$ otherwise. How do I compute the expected value of G(x)?

I tried to approximate by a second-order Taylor expansion, but I need the exact value.
Using just the definition I get stuck and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If $X_0=0$, then you can write your expectation in terms of gamma function.

Answer (score 1):

As usual :

$$\mathbb E[f(X)]=\int_{\Omega }f(X)\,\mathrm d \mathbb P=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\mu_X(\mathrm d x),$$
where $\mu_X$ is the measure induced by $X$ on $\mathbb R$. In your case, it gives $$\mathbb E[G(X)]=\int_0^\infty \sqrt xe^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma ^2t}}\,\mathrm d x=...$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not being able to proceed just through the definition. I don't know how to simplify the expression.

Comment: @P3as: I edited.

Comment: I don't think a closed-form expression for this integral exists unless $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I don't think so too.